# Learning Complex Geometry and Hodge Structure

Tags: reference-request, complex-geometry, online-resources

For the past few weeks I have been starting to learn about complex geometry and Hodge theory. I'm doing so with the book of *Daniel Huybrechts Complex Geometry*, which is an excellent book, however I would like to supplement this book with some online lectures.

Is there anyone who can recommend me a lecture series which I can use to learn about complex geometry and related topics?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Books**

1.You can refer to *Complex Manifolds* written by James Morrow and Kunihiko Kodaira.

**It is an excellent primer including a lot of calculations and details.**

2.You can refer to *Principal of Algebraic Geometry* written by Griffiths and Harris and *Complex Analytic and Differential Geometry* written by Jean-Pierre Demailly.

**They have more differential-geometric points of view.**

3.You can refer to *Hodge Theory and Complex Algebraic Geometry 1* written by Claire Voisin.

**It may be more difficult and advanced and have more algebraic points of view.**

---

**Notes and Lectures**

1.Notes about complex manifolds which is a wonderful supplement of the Huybrechts' book.

:https://www.math.stonybrook.edu/~cschnell/pdf/notes/complex-manifolds.pdf

2.New lectures written by Hossein Movasati about the Hodge theory.

:http://w3.impa.br/~hossein/myarticles/hodgetheory.pdf

3.If you interested in Kahler Manifolds,you can see the lectures written by Werner Ballmann.

:http://people.mpim-bonn.mpg.de/hwbllmnn/archiv/kaehler0609.pdf

---

**Videos**

1.Hans-Joachim Hein's Complex Geometry that consisting of ten classes  is nice. 
See here ：https://m.youtube.com/results?search_query=complex+geometry

2.Complex Analytic and Algebraic Geometry by
Qaisar Latif.

See here：  https://m.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLWy-AYZriyMGZjZQ7I8kYhZhtlUzFcWcz

Comment: Thank you very much, however I would also be very interested in online video lectures. Do you know any?

Comment: I added it in my answer. Hope you have a wonderful trip in complex geometry！

Comment: ad Videos, 1. Is the course by Hein still available? Can't find it.

Comment: Dear @Mathy, I also cannot find it, anyway there're still several nice resources online.